# finish() is destroying my object

Tags: java, android, class

I have an activity that creates a new instance of a class i created called `classA`. In `classA` i have a method that adds an object to a STATIC `arrayList` located in `classA`.

So my activity looks something like this:

```
SecondaryActivity extends Activity {

// creating instance of classA:
classA ca = new classA();

// method that adds object to arrayList:
ca.addObject(Object);
```

After i add the object i want to return to my main activity so i call `SecondaryActivity.this.finish()`

...which works fine but only problem is that in my main activity, the arrayList doesn't hold the object i added.

I put some Log methods inside the secondaryActivity, and i see that i successfully added an object to the arrayList but after i call `finish()` it isn;t there. I assume that what is happening is that `finish()` destroys my reference to `classA` which then destroys my object i added.

Im not sure if this is what is happening or not. Can someone please explain to me an effective way of doing what i want to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider using `singleton` for what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: alright im new to programming - whats a singleton?

Comment: Singleton is a code design pattern. It's purpose is to have only one instance of a class created. Take a look [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/singleton-design-pattern-%E2%80%93). Using "lazy initialization" you can create one instance of arrayList and then use .getInstance() from second activity to add object into it. Also note that I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, but you may try and consider it.

Comment: Thank you, i think i almost figured out my problem - one more thing, which activity lifecycle method is called on a parent activity after its child activity calls on itslef onfinish() which make it return to activity that called it?

Comment: It worked!! thanks and sorry i cant upvote your comments - i dont have enough rep. :(

Comment: if you want to "get confirmation" of object added from second activity, search for `startactivityforresult` in documentation you can use it to handle successful add in your original activity. it's fine, glad I could be helpful :)

Comment: Also, if you solved your question in your own way, please post your solution as an answer to your question below and accept it. It may help other users searching for similar problem and it also moves this question from _unanswered_ category. If my _singleton_ suggestion is what you used, I could also post it with explanation below and you can accept that if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was that i was checking the `ArrayList` in my `onCreate` method of my mainActivity, therefore, when i called `finish()` on its child activity, it didn't call `onCreate()` on my main.

So instead i reset the `classA` in mainActivity in the `onStart()` methd and it worked fine.